# Deploying a modified Jenkins image in openshift fails

Tags: jenkins, docker-registry, openshift-enterprise

I used a "jenkins-1-centos7" image to deploy in my openshift to run projects on my jenkins image.
It successfully worked and after many configurations, I duplicated a new image out of this jenkins container.
Now I want to use this image to be used as a base for further development, but deploying a pod on to this image fails with the error "ErrImagePull".

On my investigations, I found that openshift needs the image to be present in the docker registry in order to deploy pods successfully.
I deployed another app for docker registries, now when I try to push my updated image into this docker registry it fails with the message *"authentication required"*. 
I've given admin privileges to my user.

```
docker push <local-ip>:5000/openshift/<new-updated-image>
The push refers to a repository [<local-ip>:5000/openshift/<new-updated-image>] (len: 1)
c014669e27a0: Preparing
unauthorized: authentication required
```

How can I make sure that the modified image gets deployed successfully?

Comment: So as far as I understand you are building your jenkins image. Pushing it in the OpenShift Registry and then trying to use it in OpenShift? What command are you performing to authenticate on your OpenShift docker registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this answer will need edits because your issue can be caused by a lot of things. (I assume you are using OpenShift origin? (opensource)). Because I see the Centos7 image for Jenkins.

First off all you need to deploy the openshift registry in the default project.

```
$ oc project default
$ oadm registry --config=/etc/origin/master/admin.kubeconfig \
    --service-account=registry
```

A registry pod will be deployed. Above the registry will be created a service (sort of endpoint which will function as loadbalancer above your pods).

This service has an IP which is inside the `172.30` range.
You can check this IP in the webconsole or perform (assuming you're still in the default project): 
$ oc get svc

```
NAME              CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                   AGE
docker-registry   172.30.22.11   <none>        5000/TCP                  8d
kubernetes        172.30.32.13      <none>        443/TCP,53/UDP,53/TCP     9d
router            172.30.42.42    <none>        80/TCP,443/TCP,1936/TCP   9d
```

So you'll need to use the service IP of your docker-registry to authenticate. You'll also need a token:

```
$ oc whoami -t
D_OPnWLdgEbiKJzvG1fm9dYdX..
```

Now you're able to perform the login and push the image:

```
$ docker login -u admin -e any@mail.com \
-p D_OPnWLdgEbiKJzvG1fm9dYdX 172.30.22.11:5000
WARNING: login credentials saved in /root/.docker/config.json
Login Succeeded

$ docker tag myimage:latest 172.30.22.11/my-proj/myimage:latest

$ docker push 172.30.22.11/my-proj/myimage:latest
```

hope this helps. You can give some feedback on this answer and tell if it works for you or which new issues you're facing.

Comment: I'm using Openshift Enterprise... and the steps you have given are the exact same steps I have followed, I deployed a registry pod, I was able to login using the token and the registry IP, and then i tagged my image.
The error I get is while pushing the image...

Comment: as which user are you pushing the image? do you have to permissions to push the image? (for example do you have the cluster-admin role)

Comment: I used my personal id <khare.ak> to push the image:
I provided admin privileges to the user by the below command:
**oadm policy add-role-to-user admin khare.ak**

Although i resolved the issue by using a local docker registry and deploying my application using that local docker registry

Comment: I would think you need add-cluster-role-to-user. You don't use the openshift-docker registry?

Comment: ok that might be the issue... I will try with that, 
as of now I removed openshift-docker registry and used local docker registry to deploy my application.
I will return to this in a week and try with openshift-docker registry taking your advice into consideration... until then local docker registry it is...

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine only last line getting authentication error

docker push 172.30.22.11/my-proj/myimage:latest

Comment: Did you trying adding **add-cluster-role-to-user** admin privileges to your user as Lorenzvth7 suggested above?

Comment: i added myself as admin :